# Define variable inside javascript "class"

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to define variables inside class bracket?
This is mycode:

```
var connection = require('../config/db.js');
var q = require('q');
var dfd = q.defer();

class M_Profil{
    constructor(){}
        getDataProfil(params){
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = ?", [params], function(err, rows, fields){
                if (err){
                    return dfd.reject(err);
                }
                return dfd.resolve(rows[0]);
            }); 
            return dfd.promise;    
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
class C_Profil{
    constructor(){}
    profil_get(req, res, next) {
            m_profil.getDataProfil(req.user.id_user)
            .then(function(result){
                if (result) {
                    res.render("manajemen_profil/manajemen_profil", {
                        person: req.user,
                        user: result,
                        message_err: req.flash('message_err'),
                        message_success: req.flash('message_success'),
                        notif: req.session.notif
                    });
                }
                else{
                    req.flash('message_err', "Id user not found");
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                req.flash('message_err', err);
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        }
}
```

It returns error when i declare variables connection, q and dfd inside class bracket. So how if I want to extends attribute in M_Profil class?

Comment: Do you want a variable or do you want an attribute (property)?

Comment: You really should put the `var dfd = q.defer()` inside the `getDataProfil` method body.

Comment: @Bergi attribute/property and variable in OOP are same aren't it?

Comment: No, they're not. A property is part of an object, a variable is a name in a scope.

Comment: Btw, what database driver are you using that still doesn't support promises natively in 2018?

Comment: Is this pure Javascript?

Comment: @DanielFaure What else would it be?

Comment: @Bergi so what is the best practice of using promise "in 2018"?

Comment: @hfbachri_ Call a method that already returns a promise, not doing your own promisification of a callback-taking method with deferreds.

Comment: Example pls. I added my controllers in my post? @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi, maybe it is Node.js

Comment: @hfbachri_ I wasn't asking for the controller, that is fine. What is `config/db.js` returning, what db library do you use?

Comment: @DanielFaure Nodejs uses pure javascript, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to say that the [nodejs] tag is missing

Comment: I use mysql package. @Bergi

Comment: @DanielFaure added brruuh

Comment: @Bergi So how to declare VARIABLE in js class?

Comment: @hfbachri_ Well you can't. A class doesn't make a scope, it just creates a constructor and a prototype object. You either place your variable outside of the class or inside one of its methods.

Comment: @Bergi how to declare properties? Inside constructor?

Comment: @hfbachri_Yes. Just `this.propertyName = value;`.

Comment: @Bergi what are benefits using instance to call method instead of just using require() to call method?